# How to round value to nearest integer

Tags: vb.net, windows

I have the following code, where I am trying to round the value to nearest integer. But I can't seem to figure out how. I have looked at a few sources but none are useful for what I am trying to achieve. Is there a method that takes care of this? or Is there a way I can do the programmatically?

Eg.

In my database table I have a column which sets a limit for a single sms char length allowed ie- 160.
[image: Screenshot]

If the input string in the form is < then max length allowed, then divide the input string / by sms lenth allowed, and round that value to nearest int.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
    If (CInt(strText.Length) <= CInt(maxSmsLength)) Then
           doubleValueReturned = (CDec(CInt(strText.Length) / CInt(singleSmsLength)))
           smsCount = Round(doubleValueReturned)
           MsgBox(smsCount)
     end if
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You want to round 0.03125 to 1? Is that correct

Comment: The input string 5 is just an example, it could be any length. I want to convert the result value. @TimSchmelter

Comment: No, please don't add unrelated tags. What you should do is explain what you are asking more clearly. Do you want all values to be converted to 1? Or just particular values. What should -0.5 be converted to? Or 1.2? Please can you describe the mathematical rules that you wish to follow.

Comment: Why do you cast `int` to `int`?: `CInt(strText.Length)`

Comment: okay, I wont do that next time. Let me make things a little clear. If the resulting value is > 0 than round the value to whatever value.

Comment: You mean round to nearest integer not whatever value surely

Comment: yes but what I have just tried isnt rounding the value to 1, with the given example as the source of my question

Comment: Yes nearest integer @Mych

Comment: Try smsCount = (CInt(CInt(strText.Length) / CInt(singleSmsLength))) and remove the line doubleValueReturned = .......

Comment: Just use Math.Ceiling(yourValue), it will round up to nearest integer.

Comment: @Harry: this should work as expected: `If strText.Length <= maxSmsLength Then
            Dim doubleValueReturned As Double = strText.Length / singleSmsLength
            Dim smsCount = CInt(Math.Round(doubleValueReturned))
            MsgBox(smsCount)
        End If`

Comment: Oh my god you are just trying to calculate how many sms are required to send an arbitrary string?

Comment: @Steve: At last the penny's dropped! It would habe been  far easier  if he'd mentioned that in the first place.

Comment: He could use the integer division and add 1 to whatever he gets

Comment: BY the way. The 160 character limit is not so absolute. http://www.nowsms.com/long-sms-text-messages-and-the-160-character-limit

Comment: @Steve: yes, exactly. `Dim smsCount As Int32
        If strText.Length > maxSmsLength Then
            smsCount = 0 ' too large ' 
        Else
            smsCount = strText.Length \ singleSmsLength + 1
        End If`

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't quite anticipate this much of a reaction. At the time, I thought I spent time on asking the question correctly. However I realise it was a little unclear.

Comment: yea you are correct, although it is a requirement for my project to set it to 160 hence the value @Steve

Comment: @Steve : No. If length = singleSmsLength length, then adding 1 will count for 2 sms, the secund being empty. The correct smsCount is `CInt(Math.Ceiling(strText.Length / singleSmsLength))`. He should check whether `strText = ""`, and use `While strText.Length > maxSmsLength` Then `smsTextGroup = strText.Substring(0, maxSmsLength)` and `strText = strText.Length.Substring(maxSmsLength)`

Comment: Math.Ceiling() method is what I needed. Also thanks for providing me ways of how to do it programmatically.

Comment: `Dim smsRequired = (str.Length \ maxSmsLength) + (IF(str.Length Mod maxSmsLength = 0, 0, 1))` no Math required to send SMS

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to your real problem (counting how many SMS messages are required to send a string of text of arbitrary size) is to use the [Integer Division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx) (`symbol \`) instead of the [Floating Point Division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx) (`symbol /`).

The division returns always an integer discarding the floating point part. 
So finding the number of SMS messages requires adding 1 to the result returned. 
There is also the problem of an SMS message of exactly 160 characters or multiple of 160 in which case adding 1 to the result of the integer division will yeld an incorrect number of messages. 
This could be easily fixed adding 1 only if the remainder of the division is not zero

```
Dim smsRequired = (str.Length \ maxSmsLength) + 
                  (IF(str.Length Mod maxSmsLength = 0, 0, 1))
```

However this is just to answer to the asker question and is not the correct solution in a real world scenario, when you want to send a message with more than 160 characters (or if the message contains some special characters) you need to split your message in less than 160 characters

This is documented here [Long SMS Text Messages and the 160 Character Limit](http://www.nowsms.com/long-SMS-text-messages-and-the-160-character-limit)